# should I #include boost/Python.hpp or boost/python.hpp?

Tags: python, c++, case-sensitive

I am exposing C++ objects to python, using boost.python.

Should I use

```
#include boost/python.hpp
```

or

```
#include boost/Python.hpp
```

?

Comment: The actual file is `python.hpp`, so you should use that and not the capitalized one.

Comment: but using Python.hpp works on my machine. Strange?

Comment: Are you doing this `#include` on a Windows machine, or a file system that isn't case-sensitive (like FAT or NTFS)? That would be the reason why. It wouldn't work on a filesystem that is case-sensitive (like most Unix-based filesystems, by default).

Comment: @zell: That probably means you have a case-insensitive filesystem, which will find the file however you capitalise it. I believe such things exist, and are even in common use, as insane as it sounds. Use the correct name if you want your code to be portable; all Boost headers are lower case only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `python.hpp` in minor cases.

It's recommended to preserve actual file case sensitiveness when including them. Go in the include directory and check the file name, make sure you include it with correct upper/lower cases.

Else, it will work smartly on Windows (not case sensitive) and will fail if one day you try to compile under Linux. You'll then have a hard time updating all your include statements....

Comment: I really wish that Windows compilers (preprocessors, really) had an option that would cause an error diagnostic if the case in the source file didn't match that of the included file (including any path component specified as part of the `#include` directive). It would make it so much easier to fix these issues in large codebases. It would be better if that option were enabled by default, but I don't see that happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ repoquery -l boost-devel
 ...
/usr/include/boost/python.hpp
 ...
```